How to return a range::view in a std::expected?
Is there a way to return a range::view in a std::expected construct? For example, in the pseudo code below, what can I write instead of the rangeType?
std::expected<rangeType, error> get_range()
{
    if (some_condition(x))
        return std::unexpected(errorcode);

    return data|ranges::views::take(x);
}


When returning a std::expected<DifficultTypeToSpell, E> from a function, one can avoid spelling the type entirely, by using the monadic interface of std::expected. Start with a std::expected<T, E> which contains either the actual error, or some default constructed T (which could even be void), and transform it with the expression that actually gives you the type that's difficult to spell.
So the code could look something like this:
auto get_range()
{
    return [] -> std::expected<void, error> {   // start with a simple type
        if (some_condition(x)) 
            return std::unexpected(error{});
        return {};
    }().transform([] {    // and then transform to the desired type
            return data | std::ranges::views::take(x);
    });
}


There isn't a good solution to this problem as far as I can see.
The best I can do is use auto return type. For this you need to change the function to return the same type on all paths. You do this by getting the type of the view with decltype and explicitly use the std::expected type on the return. For the unexpected value, I use the std::expected constructor overload with the std::unexpected_t tag.
auto get_range()
{
    auto r = data | std::ranges::views::take(x);

    if (some_condition(x))
        return std::expected<decltype(r), error>{std::unexpect, error{}};
    

    return std::expected<decltype(r), error>{r};
}

This will put the range view type into the prototype of the function. This means that modifying the implementation in how you build r or changing the data type will change the function prototype. (because each view has a distinct type). This can be a problem or not depending on your use case of the function.
Views are lazy so constructing r before checking your condition should not be a problem. However if it is or if you want to avoid that you can get the type of r with std::declval, but it's cumbersome and brittle.

This could be a solution, thanks. The problem I see is that "some_condition", in my case, depends on x (I edit my post to show that), so the "take(x)" could lead to some kind of error.

I don't see how this changes anything. What do you mean by "some kind of error" and how would that affect the answer?

@yannick your question may get rolled back to an earlier version, since you edited it to possibly invalidate a seemingly-correct answer.

@bolov, you are right, it doesn't change anything. Your solution works, thanks again

The range type is complicated, the shortest you can do is infer their type from their use using decltype and declval.
for example
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> arr;
   decltype(std::declval<std::vector<int>&>() | std::views::take(5)) r = arr | std::views::take(5);
}

the type of r is very complicated to write, also if you try to return it from the function the range could be dangling, and you can only return 1 range type, so you cannot conditionally apply different transforms.
the better alternative is to pass in a functor like what std::for_each does and apply it to the range, this way you don't risk using a dangling range, otherwise it might be safer to return a std::vector and bite the bullet, maybe use pmr::vector to reduce allocations overhead.

thanks for the answer, std::vector might be the easiest solution. But I find it strange (maybe even disapointing) that two recently added features in C++ don't get along together very well...

I prefer to use trailing return types when the return type gets complicated.
It could look like this and the rest of your function stays unchanged:
auto get_range() -> std::expected<decltype(data | std::ranges::views::take(x)),
                                  decltype(errorcode)> {
    if (some_condition(x))
        return std::unexpected(errorcode);

    return data | std::ranges::views::take(x);
}

